# in depth working of modulus function in C

Tags: c, operators

the output of the function would be 4, but i am unable to understand why is this so. Its much appreciated if you can reason to what happens when for  x%y, when y > x

```
int main()
{
 int x=4%5;
 printf("x=%d\n",x);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the remainder when you divide 4 by 5? That's the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`4 / 5 = 0` and `0 * 5 + 4 = 4`, so the remainder is `4`.

C defines `%`, the remainder operator, as (in c11, 6.5.5p6):

```
(a/b)*b + a%b shall equal a.
```

Comment: `(a/b)*b + a%b`- isn't it recursive?

Comment: so the result for x%y would always be x? when y>x?

Comment: @N0062eclipse yes, for positive `x` and `y`.

Comment: (a/b)*b + a%b , by BODMAS then a/b gets evaluated first followed by *b then a%b then + wont that result in 2a?

Comment: @Ajay I fail to understand your comment

Comment: @ouah If operator `%` is defined such way that involves `%` itself, it is recursive.

Comment: @Ajay I can see only one occurrence of `%` in the definition so I fail to see the recursion.

Comment: @ouah, You cannot give definition of `+` operator as: `a+b-b` shall equal `a`.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, here's what `a%b` does for negative, zero and positive `a`, where `b` is +3 and -3:

```
  a = -6:  b=+3  a/b = -2  a%b = +0  :  b=-3  a/b = +2  a%b = +0
  a = -5:  b=+3  a/b = -1  a%b = -2  :  b=-3  a/b = +1  a%b = -2
  a = -4:  b=+3  a/b = -1  a%b = -1  :  b=-3  a/b = +1  a%b = -1
  a = -3:  b=+3  a/b = -1  a%b = +0  :  b=-3  a/b = +1  a%b = +0
  a = -2:  b=+3  a/b = +0  a%b = -2  :  b=-3  a/b = +0  a%b = -2
  a = -1:  b=+3  a/b = +0  a%b = -1  :  b=-3  a/b = +0  a%b = -1
  a = +0:  b=+3  a/b = +0  a%b = +0  :  b=-3  a/b = +0  a%b = +0
  a = +1:  b=+3  a/b = +0  a%b = +1  :  b=-3  a/b = +0  a%b = +1
  a = +2:  b=+3  a/b = +0  a%b = +2  :  b=-3  a/b = +0  a%b = +2
  a = +3:  b=+3  a/b = +1  a%b = +0  :  b=-3  a/b = -1  a%b = +0
  a = +4:  b=+3  a/b = +1  a%b = +1  :  b=-3  a/b = -1  a%b = +1
  a = +5:  b=+3  a/b = +1  a%b = +2  :  b=-3  a/b = -1  a%b = +2
  a = +6:  b=+3  a/b = +2  a%b = +0  :  b=-3  a/b = -2  a%b = +0
```

which shows that: `a == ((a / b) * b) + (a % b)` as advertised.  You will observe that the sign of `b` is immaterial, the result has the same sign as `a`.

Also, `((-a) % b) == -(a % b)` -- that is, you can work out what `a % b` is going to do taking the absoulute values of both, and giving the result the sign of `a`.

Note that `a / b` (for integers) is defined to "truncate (towards zero)" (C99 6.5.5), so for `-2 / +3` the answer is `0`.  This is important for the definition of `%`.  It is this truncation which is responsible for the pattern above being symmetrical about zero.

Note further that this is **not** the same as conventional arithmetic remainder (per Euclidean division) where the remainder is always positive (or zero) -- irrespective of the sign of either of the arguments.  Euclidean division says: `q = a / b, where a = q * b + r, and 0 <= r < abs(b)`, where `r` is the remainder.  This gives a different pattern:

```
  a = -6:  b=+3  q=-2  r=0  :  b=-3  q=+2  r=0
  a = -5:  b=+3  q=-2  r=1  :  b=-3  q=+2  r=1
  a = -4:  b=+3  q=-2  r=2  :  b=-3  q=+2  r=2
  a = -3:  b=+3  q=-1  r=0  :  b=-3  q=+1  r=0
  a = -2:  b=+3  q=-1  r=1  :  b=-3  q=+1  r=1
  a = -1:  b=+3  q=-1  r=2  :  b=-3  q=+1  r=2
  a = +0:  b=+3  q=+0  r=0  :  b=-3  q=+0  r=0
  a = +1:  b=+3  q=+0  r=1  :  b=-3  q=+0  r=1
  a = +2:  b=+3  q=+0  r=2  :  b=-3  q=+0  r=2
  a = +3:  b=+3  q=+1  r=0  :  b=-3  q=-1  r=0
  a = +4:  b=+3  q=+1  r=1  :  b=-3  q=-1  r=1
  a = +5:  b=+3  q=+1  r=2  :  b=-3  q=-1  r=2
  a = +6:  b=+3  q=+2  r=0  :  b=-3  q=-2  r=0
```

Which is clearly not symmetrical about zero any more.  But the pattern for `q` and `r` starts somewhere around -infinity, and proceeds, unbroken, through zero and towards +infinity (and beyond).

Answer (score 0):

The modulus operation would be as  x%y and two conditions exist if x>y and if y>x. If x>y the remainder after operation x/y would be the answer. If y>x, x would be the answer because if 4%5 it would calculate 4/5 first and it would be 0. So  0*5+4 will be the equation and 4 is the remainder. So if in x%y if y>x the output will be x.